# ¿Cómo hacer que una tabla no atraviese/que empuje una imagen en html?

Tags: html, css, web

Estoy haciendo una página web para una compañía, y decidí usar Lorem Ipsum para rellenar mientras espero a que me den información. En una sección tengo una tabla con 3 columnas, estas siendo el nombre de una función, imagen representativa (actualmente en blanco) y una descripción de dicha función (de ahí el Lorem Ipsum), el código de esto es:

```html
<div class = "center-fit">
    <table align="center" style="color: white" class="center-fit">
        <tr>
        <th> EXPLORA </th>
        <th> DESCUBRE </th>
        <th> COMBATE </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <th><img src="white_chico.png"style="width:100%";></th>
        <th><img src="white_chico.png"style="width:100%";></th>
        <th><img src="white_chico.png"style="width:100%";></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a dictum augue. Nunc tortor metus, facilisis id molestie a, accumsan a risus. Nullam magna risus, vestibulum sit amet cursus sed, pretium at turpis. Nulla lectus ante, volutpat ut purus sit amet, posuere volutpat nibh. Nulla lobortis consectetur tellus. Nullam pellentesque sit amet nisl id pellentesque. Fusce a justo enim. Proin viverra sollicitudin massa, vel feugiat elit rutrum a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam vitae ex eu nibh pharetra consectetur eget sed mi.</th>
        <th>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a dictum augue. Nunc tortor metus, facilisis id molestie a, accumsan a risus. Nullam magna risus, vestibulum sit amet cursus sed, pretium at turpis. Nulla lectus ante, volutpat ut purus sit amet, posuere volutpat nibh. Nulla lobortis consectetur tellus. Nullam pellentesque sit amet nisl id pellentesque. Fusce a justo enim. Proin viverra sollicitudin massa, vel feugiat elit rutrum a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam vitae ex eu nibh pharetra consectetur eget sed mi.</th>
        <th>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a dictum augue. Nunc tortor metus, facilisis id molestie a, accumsan a risus. Nullam magna risus, vestibulum sit amet cursus sed, pretium at turpis. Nulla lectus ante, volutpat ut purus sit amet, posuere volutpat nibh. Nulla lobortis consectetur tellus. Nullam pellentesque sit amet nisl id pellentesque. Fusce a justo enim. Proin viverra sollicitudin massa, vel feugiat elit rutrum a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam vitae ex eu nibh pharetra consectetur eget sed mi.</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
<br>
```

En un navegador de computador se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así se ve  en mi teléfono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, la tabla atraviesa la imagen que esta abajo (sé que tengo un problema con el bloque de texto, lo estoy reparando en ese momento).

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

¿Hay una forma de hacer que la tabla "empuje" la imagen hacia abajo?

EDIT, agrego el código que tengo para agregar la imagen:

```html
<br>

<div style="text-align: center;">


<div class="container">
  <img src="white_medio.png" alt="baño" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="text-block">
    <h4>Un lugar misterioso</h4>
    <p>
    &#191;Que paso aqui?<br> &#191;Que hago aqui?<br> &#191;Que son estas maquinas?,<br> Estas son solo algunas preguntas que deberás responder</p>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda si agregas la parte de como agregas la imagen, pues yo he replicado tu ejercicio y no visualizo el comportamiento descrito

Comment: Listo, ahí lo agregué

Comment: ¿es posible que tengas puesto un position:absolute para la class 'container' en tu css? de ser así deberías bien pasarlo a relative o bien posicionarlo donde realmente quieres que se situe con top o bottom. Si compartes su css también te podrá ayuda mejor algún compañero.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que no utilices la etiqueta `<table>` para dividir tu web por columnas para estas cosas se utilizan los `<div>` como veras en mi ejemplo.

para tu cuestión de que la web se vea bien en otro tipo de dispositivos que no sean un monitor te he dejado un ejemplo de una `media query` en este caso he utilizado una que detecta cuando tu aplicación se esta ejecutando en una pantalla menor a 480px

`@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)`

esto es muy útil porque cuando ocurre esto hago los elementos ocupen todo el ancho y los ordeno con el `display:block` para que se muestren de uno en uno.

para terminar te recomiendo utilizar [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) para el diseño de tus web y sobre todo el tema de los grid de boostrap te hará la vida mas fácil a la hora de colocar elementos y de ver tu web en varios formatos de pantalla.

```css
 .card{
  width:30%;
    margin:auto;
 }
 .center-fit {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
 }
 
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
 .card{
  width:100%;
 }
 .center-fit {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class = "center-fit">
  <div class="card">
   <h4>EXPLORA</h4>
   <div>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"style="width:100%";>
   </div>
   <div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a dictum augue. Nunc tortor metus, facilisis id molestie a, accumsan a risus. Nullam magna risus, vestibulum sit amet cursus sed, pretium at turpis. Nulla lectus ante, volutpat ut purus sit amet, posuere volutpat nibh. Nulla lobortis consectetur tellus. Nullam pellentesque sit amet nisl id pellentesque. Fusce a justo enim. Proin viverra sollicitudin massa, vel feugiat elit rutrum a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam vitae ex eu nibh pharetra consectetur eget sed mi.
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <h4>DESCUBRE</h4>
   <div>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"style="width:100%";>
   </div>
   <div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a dictum augue. Nunc tortor metus, facilisis id molestie a, accumsan a risus. Nullam magna risus, vestibulum sit amet cursus sed, pretium at turpis. Nulla lectus ante, volutpat ut purus sit amet, posuere volutpat nibh. Nulla lobortis consectetur tellus. Nullam pellentesque sit amet nisl id pellentesque. Fusce a justo enim. Proin viverra sollicitudin massa, vel feugiat elit rutrum a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam vitae ex eu nibh pharetra consectetur eget sed mi.
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <h4>COMBATE</h4>
   <div>
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"style="width:100%";>
   </div>
   <div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a dictum augue. Nunc tortor metus, facilisis id molestie a, accumsan a risus. Nullam magna risus, vestibulum sit amet cursus sed, pretium at turpis. Nulla lectus ante, volutpat ut purus sit amet, posuere volutpat nibh. Nulla lobortis consectetur tellus. Nullam pellentesque sit amet nisl id pellentesque. Fusce a justo enim. Proin viverra sollicitudin massa, vel feugiat elit rutrum a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam vitae ex eu nibh pharetra consectetur eget sed mi.
   </div>
   
  </div>
    </div>
```